# function not returning expected value typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that check the stock through api call and i am calling it into another function. but this always return true before the excecution of apimethod.post seems like apimethod.post evaluate after if condition. 
any help?

```
public IsStockAvailable = (): any => {
  return this.apimethod.post(url, body, true).subscribe((response: any) => {
    if (response.RCode == AppConstant.ResponseStatus.StockError) {
      return false;
    }
    if (response.RCode == AppConstant.ResponseStatus.Success) {
      return true;
    }
  })
}

AddItem(){
if(!IsStockAvailable ){
    return;
  }
   // other part of code
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return observable from subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935721/how-to-return-observable-from-subscribe)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call your function in the if statement

```
if(!IsStockAvailable() ){
    return;
}
```

otherwise, you just pass a function definition to the if statement and it is truthy !!